# chat server setup in dotnet backend and flutter as front end

Tags: .net, flutter, chat

I am very much not clear about how to set up chat application for flutter app. I have found lots of examples as running both the client and server from front end itself for flutter chat apps. But my doubt is, since I have a back end in dot net and I can set up or save the chats in dot net, why I need a separate chat server?
Or inorder to setup my dotnet server for a chat to receive and save what should I do?

Comment: if you want to make realtime chat app you have to create socket server otherwise you dont

Comment: Thank you for the response, May I know in detail as how we do in client flutter app and what needed to be done in the dot net backend?